# Compile C++ and MASM together

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, masm

I'm doing an exercise of an online course about [MASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler), specifically a project that uses both C++ and MASM.

The code of the C++ file is this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" void reverser(int *y, const int *x, int n);

int main() {
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    const int n = 10;
    int x[n], y[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        x[i] = i;

    reverser(y, x, n);

    for(int i = 0x0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("x: %5d     y: %5d", x[i], y[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code of the MASM file is this:

```
.386
.model flat, c
.code

reverser    proc
            push ebp
            mov ebp,esp
            push esi
            push edi        ; Function Prologue

            xor eax,eax
            mov edi,[ebp+8]
            mov esi,[ebp+12]
            mov ecx,[ebp+16]
            test ecx,ecx

            lea esi,[esi+ecx*4-4]
            pushfd
            std

@@:         lodsd
            mov [edi], eax
            add edi,4
            dec ecx
            jnz @B

            popfd
            mov eax,1

            pop edi
            pop esi
            pop ebp

            ret

reverser endp
         end
```

In the online course, the person speaking compiles it without any problem using Visual Studio, but if I try to compile the .cpp file using GCC, I get an error:

> undefined reference to 'reverser'

So I tried to add

```
#include "reverser.asm"
```

to the code, but then I get the errors:

```
reverser.asm:1:error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
reverser.asm:1:error: expected ',' or ';' before numeric constant
reverser.asm:9:error: 'Prologo' does not name a type
reverser.asm:21:error: stray '@' in program
```

So I have the following questions:

1. How can I fix this?
2. How I can compile the two files together on Windows using the command-line? Like using *masm.exe* and *gcc.exe* to compile.
3. Why did it compile without any problem in the course?

Comment: You have to assemble the assembler code with the assembler, not the C++ compiler. You can't just `#include` it into the C++.

Comment: Make sure MASM is added to the project build customzations then add `reverser.asm` to the project and remove the `#include "reverser.asm"`

Comment: @MichaelPetch I don't have a project, I'm using the command-line

Comment: @user207421 You mean I need to use masm.exe for both the cpp and asm file? I would try to usie gcc for the cpp file and masm.exe for the asm and then try to link them together but I didn't success to build the cpp file for the error I wrote above :l

Comment: No you would assemble reverser.asm to an object file reverser.obj. Compile the c file to an object file using your C++ compiler. You would then use the linker to link both object files together to build an EXE. You shoudl show us the commands you use to compile, assemble and link

Comment: @MichaelPetch As I said I cannot compile the cpp program because I get error and I don't understand why so actually I don't have tryed to link the object files together.
Do you know why I get the error that the funcion "reverser" is not defined?

Comment: Please see the second half of the comment about showing the commands you are using to compile, assemble and link. Update your question with that info pls.

Comment: It should be noted that Visual Studio will be using MSVC++ as a compiler and not GCC. The Visual Studio environment understands how to compile and link ASM and C/C++ files with the proper options. That is why it probably works. Which GCC compiler you are using may also be an issue. Are you using MINGW GCC? TDM-GCC?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I am compiling with "gcc program-name.cpp" and I get the error I shared. to assemble I just use "masm program-name.asm" and I didn't linked anything for now/
I am using MINGW

Comment: As well as MinGW, you'll also need MASM or JWASM to assemble that `.asm` file.  And to get your `.c` file to assemble, you need to remove the `#include "reverser.asm"` line.  `#include` is the same as copy/pasting the text into the file before the compiler sees it, which obviously can't work if the text isn't valid C syntax.  Michael Petch already commented about this.  After fixing that, `g++ -Wall -c  foo.cpp` should work to make `foo.obj`

Comment: @PeterCordes : his question says he's using MASM already

Comment: I compiled the cpp with g++ and the asm with masm. Now how do I link them together?

Comment: You could try linking with g++. After creating an object for your program (ie: program.obj for the C++ code) and reverser.obj from MASM you could try linking with `g++ program.obj reverser.obj -o program.exe`   If you are using a 64-bit compiler every time you use g++ you may have to also use `-m32` to force it to process things as 32-bit code. That's assuming you compiled your C++ code to program.obj with something like `g++ -c program.cpp`

Comment: @MichaelPetch With "g++ program.obj reverser.obj -o program.exe" I get "reverser.obj: file not recognized: File format not recognized"

Comment: Assemble reverser.obj with `ml /c reverser.asm` then do the link again. What does it say?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Doing g++ program.o program.obj -o program.exe I get the same error "reverser.obj: file not recognized: File format not recognized"

Comment: @MichaelPetchwith With -m32 used on the compilation of the cpp program and on the linking I get the same error "reverser.obj: file not recognized: File format not recognized"

Comment: @MichaelPetch the code is above in the question

Comment: @MichaelPetch oh ok I send you now

Comment: Okay I think I know one problem. And I should have asked this yesterday. You mentioned you run MASM. Looking at the reverser.obj it appears to be an 8088 object (DOS) and not a 32-bit COFF object (Win32). What version of MASM are you using (you should be able to tell by running MASM without options). In one of my comments I mentioned using `ml /c reverser.asm` to assemble to an object (ML is the 32 bit assembler and linker).

Comment: If you don't have a new version of MASM for generating windows programs and object files you can use a very good open source version that should work just fine. JWASM can assemble MASM code and generate compatible MASM output. Can be downloaded here: https://japheth.de/JWasm.html . Then just assembler the `reverser.asm` to a COFF object file using `jwasm -coff reverser.asm`

Comment: If you have a version of MASM like what comes with [MASM32](https://www.masm32.com/) (v6.1x) then you should be able to use `ml /coff /c reverser.asm` to generate reverser.obj that can be used with Win32 development. The default for versions of MASM earlier than 8.0 was `/omf`, for versions of MASM >= 8.0 it changed to `/coff`